# $t(n) = t(\alpha n) + t(\beta n) + cn$ , $\alpha + \beta \lt 1, c > 0$ Using tree recursion

Tags: algorithms, recursion, trees, recursive-algorithms

**Solve** $$t(n) = t(\alpha n) + t(\beta n) + cn$$ $$ \alpha + \beta \lt 1, c > 0$$

**Using tree recursion**

I've taken this problem when $\alpha + \beta = 1, t(n)= t(n/3) + t(2n/3) + n$

And I've got that it is $\Theta(nlogn)$

Can anyone explain how can I solve this when $\alpha + \beta < 1$ ? Maybe there's some reference in the internet already for this..

Comment: You could just apply the Master Theorem.

Comment: @AlexR. I'm studying right now the Master Theorem. It's kinda wierd and I'm not sure how to apply it because it says here $T(n) = a \cdot T(\frac{n}{b}) + f(n)$. but I have twice $t$ in my right side of the equation, how can I use $a$ and $b$ properly to prove it?

Comment: The result is
$\Theta(n)$. I proved this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506489/if-tn-un-sum-i-t-lfloor-r-i-n-rfloor-show-that-tn-thetan

Comment: @martycohen I just found here, in the bottom of the page that it says $\Theta(n)$. https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960130.html , and I find hard to understand your proof. I'll stick to Master's theorem I guess. I'm trying to figure how to to use it though. Will update later

Comment: @martycohen I've posted a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Building a tree:**

**We have to compute the work done:**

$n$ - first line, **root**

$n/a + n / b$ - second line, **children of root** (sum of it $n/a + n/b$)

and like that so on..

Then we sum all the lines(because **we need to sum all the work done**), and we'll see that we will never exceed $n$.

So the answer is $\Theta(n)$